# Passing state between nested components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to open up a Modal component on a onClick from a listItem in a listGroup component. However, the setup I currently have either causes my application to hang and I am not able to click anything on the application or the state does not get updated and the modal does not render.

Another weird that thing that occurs is when I console log to see what the showModalState is, the state changes but when I check the react developer tools to see if it changed, it's always at the initial state which is false.

The error more than likely comes from the ModalActions.ts or ModalReducer.ts. 
Note: All the code provided below are just snippets. I omitted alot of stuff and left only what I thought could be the issue.

This is my ModalTypes.ts

```
export const SHOW_MODAL = "SHOW_MODAL";

interface ShowModal {
  type: typeof SHOW_MODAL;
  payload: boolean;
}

export type ModalActionTypes = ShowModal;
```

This is my ModalActions.ts

```
import { SHOW_MODAL, ModalActionTypes } from "./ModalTypes";

export function UpdateModal(modal: boolean): ModalActionTypes {
  return {
    type: SHOW_MODAL,
    payload: modal
  };
}
```

This is my IModalState.ts

```
export interface IModalState {
  showModal: boolean;
}
```

This is my ModalReducer.ts. **I will probably make actions and types to hide the modal as well

```
import { ModalActionTypes, SHOW_MODAL } from "../actions/ModalTypes";
import { IModalState } from "../models/IModalState";

const initialState: IModalState = {
  showModal: false
};

export function modalReducer(state = initialState, action: ModalActionTypes) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        showModal: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is my App.tsx

```
      <ListGroup
          onUpdateModal={this.props.onUpdateModal}
          showModalState={this.props.showModalState}
        />


const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  showModalState: state.modal
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    onUpdateModal: bindActionCreators(UpdateModal, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

This is my ListGroup.tsx

```
import { UpdateModal } from "../actions/ModalActions";
import { IModalState } from "../models/IModalState";

interface IProps {
  onUpdateModal: typeof UpdateModal;
  showModalState: IModalState;
}

// interface IState {
//   showModal: boolean;
// }

export class ListGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  // IState
  // public state: IState = {
  //   showModal: false
  // };

  // showModal = () => {
  //   // Show the modal
  //   this.setState({ showModal: true });
  // };

  public render() {
    // const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul
          className="list-group"
          style={{
            marginTop: "20px",
            display: "inline-block"
          }}
        >
          {filterTests.map(filterTest => (
            <li
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.onUpdateModal(true);
                console.log(this.props.onUpdateModal(true));
                console.log(this.props.showModalState);
                this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest(filterTest);

                // this.showModal();
              }}
            >
              {filterTest.companyPN}: {filterTest.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        {/* Show the modal if showModal is true */}
        {this.props.showModalState && (
          <TestGroup
            testState={this.props.testState}
            onUpdateSelectedWedge={this.props.onUpdateSelectedWedge}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This my TestGroup.tsx

```
interface IProps {
  onUpdateModal: typeof UpdateModal;
  showModalState: IModalState;
}

export class TestGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  // hideModal = () => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     showModal: !this.props.showModal
  //   });
  // };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="modal" style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                  <h5 className="modal-title"></h5>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className="modal-body">
                </div>

                <div className="modal-footer">
                  <button
                    // onClick={() => {
                    //   this.hideModal();
                    // }}
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                  >
                    Close
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestGroup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apps.tsx instead of this.props.showModalState it should have been this.props.showModalState.showModal

```
{this.props.showModalState.showModal && (
          <TestGroup
            testState={this.props.testState}
            onUpdateSelectedWedge={this.props.onUpdateSelectedWedge}
          />
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather leave this as a comment, but I don't have the privilege at the moment.

In your app.ts `mapStateToProps` function, I think you want `showModalState` to be

```
showModalState: state.modal.showModal
```